# Specific Date Format in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, localization

I have an app that must show Dates in Chinese. Currently, I have the following:

```
string formattedDate = "";
var dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse("06/01/2015", out dateTime))
{
  formattedDate = dateTime.ToShortDateString();
}
```

Right now, `formattedDate` gets set to `1/6/2015` when my culture is set to "zh-HK". However, I would really like it to look like: `2015年06月01日` How do I do that in C#?

Comment: What you want is `dateTime.ToLongDateString();` not `dateTime.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom format:

```
formattedDate = dateTime.ToString("yyyy'年'MM'月'dd'日'");
```

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, what are the single quotes in the string for?  Your example seems to work both with and without them. And I've never seen that before.  I wouldn't mind learning something new. :)

Comment: @sstan: The apostrophes is for literal values in the format. They are needed if you want to put something in the format that would otherwise be interpreted as a formatting code. I put them around the chinese characters as I wasn't certain that they would not be interfering with the format codes.

Answer (score 1):

```
string formattedDate = "";
var dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse("06/01/2015", out dateTime))
{
  formattedDate = dateTime.ToLongDateString(); // switch to "ToLongDateString"
}


//short date format = 1/6/2015
//long date format = 2015年06月01日
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DateTimeFormatInfo.  Guffa solution is hard coding the Chinese characters.

```
           DateTimeFormatInfo info = new CultureInfo("zh-HK", false).DateTimeFormat;

            string formattedDate = "";
            var dateTime = DateTime.MinValue;
            if (DateTime.TryParse("06/01/2015", out dateTime))
            {
                formattedDate = dateTime.ToString(info.LongDatePattern);
            }​
```